# In PHP/MySQL trying to Insert X number of rows with Value1 always the same, and Value2 equal to a value from an array with X number of values

Tags: php, mysql

This has probably been asked before, but I'm having a hard time finding an answer to this.

Let's say I have an Array and a Variable of unknown length, in PHP.

For example:

```
$value1 = 123;  
$array = array("apples", "oranges", "bananas");
```

Because the array has 3 values, I want to insert them into 3 MySQL rows like this:

```
(123, apples)  
(123, oranges)  
(123, bananas)
```

But the tricky part is that the array can be any length. Sometimes it's just 1 value, sometimes it's 5 values, etc.

I know I could count the array, and loop the MySQL insert statement in PHP, but I was hoping there was a simpler way to do this with a single MySQL statement.

Comment: Your best bet will be to iterate through your array and insert the values during each iteration.  My suggestion would be to make a prepared statement and then loop through your data, bind your values, execute the statement.  The prepared statement route will allow you to only send the data payload per iteration (instead of the entire query) and will help protect you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a single query to execute this.
Given a PDO instance in $pdo, and using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection:

```
$value1 = 123;  
$array = array("apples", "oranges", "bananas");

$values = [];
$list = "";
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $values[] = $value1;
    $values[] = $item;
    $list .= "(?,?),";
}
$list = rtrim($list, ','); // Chop off the last comma
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES $list"; // Would be like INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)...
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For($i=0;$i<arr.len;$i++){
//your SQL query be like 
Insert into table values($value1,array[$i]);
}
```

How much more simple do you want? Write a stored procedure then call it from your PHP If you want a one liner SQL statement but the above approach is the simplest I guess

Comment: If that's the best solution, that's what I'll do. As I said at the bottom of the question, I know how to loop through it and insert each row one at a time. I was really hoping there was some special MySQL magic I didn't know about that would allow something like `$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (123,(apples,oranges,bananas))";` and it would understand and convert that to 3 rows. If nothing like that exists, then your solution is the best option I can come up with as well.